# Keras： K.reshape(x, (-1, input_dim)) meaning

Tags: keras

In reccurent.py, there are some codes like this

```
from .. import backend as K
x = K.reshape(x,(-1,input_dim)) 
x = K.reshape(x, (-1, timesteps, output_dim))
```

To see the effect of K.reshape, I type the following codes in Python console:

```
from keras import backend as K
input_dim = 1 # input_dim = x.shape[2], and x has the shape(60000,784,1)
xnew = K.reshape(x,(-1,input_dim)
```

The resultant xnew has the shape 'Shape.0'.

I don't know what is the meaning of this.

And, what the difference of K.reshape() is from the conventional reshape function?

Answer (score 1):

`K.reshape` will not only reshape the array but also convert the array into a tensor structure using your backend.

I have tensorflow as my backend. So after running your code, I got `xnew` to be `<tf.Tensor 'Reshape_56:0' shape=(47040000, 1) dtype=float64>`